# Implementing the Tak function using tail recursion

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization, tail-recursion

Is it possible to implement the [Tak function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tak_%28function%29):

[image]

tail recursively in C/C++ in a way so that gcc/g++ can perform tail-recursion optimization?
I'm not sure if the nested recursive function calls will confuse the compiler.

Comment: I don't see as it would? Since it would just start doing them all, and keep branching?

Answer (score 1):

Tail recursion optimization in C++ requires that there only be 1 recursive call (which basically allows it to be converted to a loop) and that recursive call is the last operation in the function:

Example:

```
unsigned int f( unsigned int a ) 
{
   if ( a == 0 ) 
   {
      return a;
   }
   return f( a - 1 );   // tail recursion
}
```

Since the Tak function requires 4 recursive calls per "iteration":

```
int tak(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (x >= y)
    {
        return z;
    }
    else
    {
        return tak(tak(x-1, y, z), tak(y-1, z, x), tak(z-1, x, y)); // this is why it cannot happen
    }
}
```

As you can see, the last call is recursive, but it has 3 recursive calls inside it.  This prevents tail-recursion optimization (and there is no logical method for converting this into a non-recursive-loop - which is required to obtain tail-recursion optimization).

Another way it can be implemented is:

```
int tak(int x, int y, int z)
{
    while (x > y) 
    {
        int oldx = x, oldy = y;
        x = tak(x - 1, y, z);
        y = tak(y - 1, z, oldx);
        if (x <= y) 
            break;
        z = tak(z - 1, oldx, oldy);
    }
    return z;
}
```

Which again shows that even in a loop form, it is still recursive, preventing tail-recursion optimization.

Comment: Would it be possible for a compiler to transform a direct implementation to the loop implementation?

Comment: @jh314 What do you mean a "direct implementation"?

Comment: The one with the statement `return tak(tak(x-1, y, z), tak(y-1, z, x), tak(z-1, x, y));`

Comment: Possible?  eh.  It is not very probable that it would see that and convert it to the loop version.  The only thing the loop buys you is a few less function calls (meaning the call stack doesn't get flooded  as much).

Answer (score 0):

Going straight from your math definition, we can just write the function as:

```
int tak(int x, int y, int z){
    if(x>y)
        return tak(tak(1-x,y,z), tak(y-1,z,x), tak(z-1,x,y));
    else
        return z;
}
```

However you can't do it with tail-recrusion as it cannot be converted into a loop. Since there is more than one recrusion call.

Comment: The number of recursive calls is not the important variable. There are functions with one recursive call that can't be turned into a loop, and there are functions with many recursive calls that can. What is important is the location of the call.

Comment: Thanks @Jules. Appreciate it!